Deep Linking using Universal Link in iOS - Swift
I had setup deep link and it is triggering the below callback in both cases when my app is in foreground or in Background. Now I have Splash View Controller, Login View Controller and Tabbarviewcontroller. I want that all the authentication that is happening in the splash or in login should work same and on successful login when user come to Tabbarviewcontroller then decide to the destination view controller. I have tried Notifications, Userdefaults but they are not working like what I want. I want to handle this case on both cases: Background/Foreground.

func application(_: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler _: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
              let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
            return false
        }
        
        handleUniversalLink(url: url)
        return true
    }
    
    
    private func handleUniversalLink(url: URL) {
        UniversalLinkManager.sharedManager.handleUniversalLink(url: url)
    }


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


import Foundation

class UniversalLinkManager {
    
    static let sharedManager = UniversalLinkManager()
    
    func handleUniversalLink(url: URL) {
        
        var queryParams: [String: String?] = [:]
        
        if let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
           let params = components.queryItems {
            for param in params {
                queryParams[param.name] = param.value
            }
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set("test", forKey: "serviceInfo")
     
    }
}

    




The solution I found to this problem is like that:
1 - Declare the notification that we will post:
extension Notification.Name {
    static let AppLoadingCompleted = Notification.Name(rawValue: "AppLoadingCompleted")
}

2 - Post this notification when your main view controller appears.
var isFirstAppear = true

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    if isFirstAppear {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .AppLoadingCompleted, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        isFirstAppear = false
    }
}

3 - Setup SceneDelegate to observe this notification. You can do this in willConnectTo function:
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appLoadingCompleted), name: .AppLoadingCompleted, object: nil)

4 - Declare the @objc appLoadingCompleted function in your sceneDelegate. It will be called after app is loaded completely.
5 - The rest is easy. You should declare pendingUniversalLink in sceneDelegate and then set it when you receive it in willConnectTo or in continue functions. When your main view controller is appeared, the appLoadingCompleted will be called and you can perform the actions after that.
